# How to make an object and put it into an array using a loop, so if I want to add data all I have to do is make a new string

Tags: c++, arrays

How to make an object and put it into an array? I want to make an array of `DailyStats` with the parameterized constructor. I want to use a loop to add to the array of objects.

```cpp
#ifndef DAILYSTATS_H
#define DAILYSTATS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class DailyStats
{
    public:
        DailyStats();
        DailyStats(string content);
        void parse(const string& line);
        double mean();
        string getDate();
        void setDate(string newDate); 

    private:
        string date;
        double temperatureValues[];
};

#endif
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "DailyStats.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
    
DailyStats::DailyStats()
{
    date = "";
    count = 0;
    temperatureValues[0];
}

DailyStats::DailyStats(string content)
{
    parse(content);
    temperatureValues[24];
    count = 0;
}

void DailyStats::parse(const string& line)
{
    string random = "";
    string random1 = "";
    char del = ' ';
    int count2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= (int)line.size(); i++)
    {
        if(count < 10)
        {
            random1 += line[i];
            setDate(random1);
            count++;
        }

        if(line[i] != del && count == 10)
        {
            random += line[i];
        }
        else if (line[i] == del && count == 10)
        {
            temperatureValues[count2] = stod(random);
            random = "";
            count2++;
        }
    }
}

double DailyStats::mean()
{
    count = 1;
    double num = 0;

    while(count <= 24)
    {
        num += temperatureValues[count];

        if(count == 24)
        {
            num = num/24;
        }

        count++;
    }

    return ceil(num * 100.0) / 100.0;
}

string DailyStats::getDate()
{
    return date;
}

void DailyStats::setDate(string newDate)
{
    date = newDate;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DailyStats.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str0 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";
    string str1 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";
    string str2 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";
    string str3 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";

    DailyStats info[4];

    info[1] = { {str0} };

    cout << info[1].mean() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see with my code, I have different strings that I would like to put in my objects to be used as the variable for my parameterized constructor. So, when I have that done, I can then call my `mean()` function so it can get the different means of the different data.

I tried it without the array, and it all works fine, but I can't figure out how to get the array to work.

Comment: There is no array in this code. Please show the code you have tried that is not working for you.  However, it is not possible to declare a *fixed* array of objects with different constructor values, so you would have to allocate a block of raw memory for the array and then use `placement-new` to construct each object inside that memory as needed. Otherwise, just use `std::vector` instead, then you can push constructed objects into it, passing in whatever constructor values you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have updated my code to show what I have tried

Comment: @RemyLebeau -- `struct S { S(const std::string&) {} }; S s[] = { str0, str1, str2, str3 };` constructs an array with the defined values.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Unless you have a reason to expect the contents of the `DailyStats` class to be relevant to causing the problem, you can show us an example with a dummy version of the class. If you "tried it without the array and it all works fine", then you should show us a representative version of code without an array, and then separately show the attempt to use an array and *explain exactly what went wrong*. "I can't figure out how to get it to work" isn't helpful; *what isn't working*?

Comment: So, now that your code assigns a value to `info[1]`, what happens? Do you get an error message from the compiler? Does the code run but produce the wrong result?

Comment: @PeteBecker when i try and make the code to run it I get this error g++ -c main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
DailyStats.hpp: In member function ‘DailyStats& DailyStats::operator=(DailyStats&&)’:
DailyStats.hpp:7:7: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
 class DailyStats
       ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:24: note: synthesized method ‘DailyStats& DailyStats::operator=(DailyStats&&)’ first required here 
     info[1] = { {str0} };
                        ^
makefile:5: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1

Comment: @NixJoe `info[1] = { {str0} };` should be either `info[1].parse(str0);` or `info[1] = DailyStats(str0);` or just `info[1] = str0;`

Comment: @NixJoe regarding the error, `double temperatureValues[];` is not a valid declaration of a class member array. Such an array can't be unbound. Use `std::vector` instead if you don't know the array size at compile-time but only at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was told to use a partially filled array of DailyStats objects to store the data.

Comment: @NixJoe And? That doesn't change what I said.

Comment: @NixJoe -- you're muddling two different arrays. `info` is an array of `DailyStats` objects; you've filled it with default-constructed objects, and then changed one of them. Fine. That's not the problem. The problem is **inside** the class `DailyStats`; its data member `double temperatureValues[]` is not a valid array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I see is that your `temperatureValues[]` array is unbound at compile-time.  That will not work.  Since you don't know the size of the array until runtime, use `std::vector` instead (in fact, you already have `#include <vector>` in your code), eg:

```cpp
#ifndef DAILYSTATS_H
#define DAILYSTATS_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>

class DailyStats
{
    public:
        DailyStats() = default;
        DailyStats(const std::string& content);
        void parse(const std::string& line);
        double mean() const;
        std::string getDate() const;
        void setDate(const std::string& newDate); 

    private:
        std::string date;
        std::vector<double> temperatureValues;
};

#endif
```

```cpp
#include "DailyStats.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>
    
DailyStats::DailyStats(const string& content)
{
    parse(content);
}

void DailyStats::parse(const string& line)
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    double value;

    iss >> date;

    temperatureValues.clear();
    while (iss >> value)
        temperatureValues.push_back(value);
}

double DailyStats::mean() const
{
    double num = 0.0;

    if (!temperatureValues.empty())
    {
        for(size_t count = 0; count < temperatureValues.size(); ++count)
        {
            num += temperatureValues[count];
        }
        num = std::ceil((num / temperatureValues.size()) * 100.0) / 100.0;
    }

    return num;
}

std::string DailyStats::getDate() const
{
    return date;
}

void DailyStats::setDate(const std::string& newDate)
{
    date = newDate;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DailyStats.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str0 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";
    string str1 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";
    string str2 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";
    string str3 = "06/01/2021 74.85 71.58 78.68 71.55 78.14 72.36 76.89 71.35 79.94 78.87 78.07 75.78 77.86 74.04 76.56 72.96 75.07 74.02 70.21 75.56 79.61 72.97 75.29 73.33 ";

    DailyStats info[4];

    info[0].parse(str0);
    info[1].parse(str1);
    info[2].parse(str2);
    info[3].parse(str3);

    cout << info[0].mean() << endl;
    cout << info[1].mean() << endl;
    cout << info[2].mean() << endl;
    cout << info[3].mean() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that makes more sense to me now and thanks for the help I really appreciate it.